# SQL values from one table into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have made a code as followed:

```
select 
PMGCONTACTPERSON.RECID                              AS  'Recid'
,PMGCONTACTPERSON.ROLEID                            AS  'Rol'
,DIRPARTYTABLE.NAME
from PMGCONTACTPERSON
left join DIRPARTYTABLE
ON  DIRPARTYTABLE.PARTYID = PMGCONTACTPERSON.PARTYID
```

[image: result query]

What I would like te get is columns named after the rolid and values filled with the names.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the desired result? This isn't as simple as renaming some columns

Comment: So you want RoleID values be something like this" Opzichter Fred"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to Pivot the table i.e. rows to columns. You can use PIVOT clause in SQL SERVER.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ROLE_NAME, NAME FROM TEST_NAME) T
PIVOT(MAX(NAME) FOR ROLE_NAME IN ([MANAGER], [ENGINEER])) AS PIVOT_TABLE;
```